# Push notification messages are not received on iPhone when sent from appery

Tags: iphone, ionic-framework, push-notification, appery.io

I have created an ionic app that can receive push notifications in Appery. I am getting the success code block executed and the device DB get updated with the device id.

But the notification is not received on device, but the status shows as sent !![image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 0):

- For Ionic you should call **PushRegisterDevice Service** when your app starts,
  see https://docs.appery.io/docs/pushnotifications-quickstart-tutorial-ionic
  You should see the `deviceId` of your phone added to `Devices` collection
- For iPhone you should have a valid iOS certificate for push notifications with `.p12` extension, it should be uploaded to Appery at *Push Notifications* page for your project, *Settings > iOS settings*

Comment: Thanks for fast fast reply. I have done both. Still issue exists

Comment: Also, we have found that only production certificates work in Appery

![Production Cert](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j1jfcqmiajdkhrn/Screenshot%202017-05-18%2012.50.16.png?dl=0)

Comment: @production Cert , First time it did work for me using development certificate. Now i am using production ...

Comment: This can be helpful:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QqijXpNy9VA&feature=youtu.be